# unable to get data from model class in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift

Here is the data for model class in which I got data from all dictionaries but unable to get ratingVotes from model class in which I need to get `value` key value pair to be used for displaying rating in my UI Can anyone help me how to resolve this ?

```
func ReviewApiDownloadJsonwithURL(reviewApi : String){
            print(reviewApi)
            let url = URL(string: reviewApi)!
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil { print(error!); return }
                do {
                    if let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [[String:Any]] {
                        for item in jsonObj {
                             self.reviewModel = Review.init(dict: item)
                        }
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            guard let obj = self.reviewModel else { return }
                            let itemsCount = obj.reviews
                            for i in 0..<itemsCount.count {
                                let customAttribute = obj.reviews[i].ratingVotes
//                                for j in 0..<customAttribute.count {
                                        self.ratingvalue.append(customAttribute[0].value!)
//                                }
                            }
                            print(self.ratingvalue)
                            self.reviewTableView.delegate = self
                            self.reviewTableView.dataSource = self
                            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                            self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
                            self.reviewTableView.reloadData()
                            self.initialCollectionData()
                        }
                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            task.resume()
    }
```

Here is my Json data

[image]

Here is my model class code

```
struct Review  {

    let ratingPercent : Any?
    let count : Any?
    let reviews : [Reviews]


    init(dict : [String:Any]) {
        if let customAttribute = dict["reviews"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
            var result = [Reviews]()
            for obj in customAttribute {
                result.append(Reviews(dict: (obj as? [String : Any])!))
            }
            self.reviews = result
        } else {
            self.reviews = [Reviews]()
        }
        self.ratingPercent = dict["avg_rating_percent"]
        self.count = dict["count"]
    }
}

struct Reviews {

    let reviewId : Any?
    let createdAt : Any?
    let entityId : Any?
    let entityValue : Any?
    let statusId : Any?
    let detailId : Any?
    let title : String?
    let detail : String?
    let nickName : String?
    let customerId : Any?
    let entityCode : Any?
    let ratingVotes : [RatingVotes]

    init(dict : [String:Any]) {
        if let customAttribute = dict["rating_votes"] as? [[String: Any]] {
            var result = [RatingVotes]()
            for obj in customAttribute {
                result.append(RatingVotes(dict: (obj as? [String : Any])!))
            }
            self.ratingVotes = result
        } else {
            self.ratingVotes = [RatingVotes]()
        }
        self.reviewId = dict["review_id"]
        self.createdAt = dict["created_at"]
        self.entityId = dict["entity_id"]
        self.entityValue = dict["entity_pk_value"]
        self.statusId = dict["status_id"]
        self.detailId = dict["detail_id"]
        self.title = dict["title"] as? String
        self.detail = dict["detail"] as? String
        self.nickName = dict["nickname"] as? String
        self.customerId = dict["customer_id"]
        self.entityCode = dict["entity_code"]
    }
}

    struct  RatingVotes {
        let voteId : Int?
        let optionId : Int?
        let remoteIp : Any?
        let remoteIpLong : Int?
        let customerId : Any?
        let entityPkValue : Any?
        let ratingId : Int?
        let reviewId : Int?
        let percent : Int?
        let value: Int?
        let ratingCode : String?
        let storeId : Int?
        let code : Int?
        let postion : Int?

        init(dict : [String:Any]) {
            self.voteId = dict["vote_id"] as? Int
            self.optionId = dict["option_id"] as? Int
            self.remoteIp = dict["remote_ip"]
            self.remoteIpLong = dict["remote_ip_long"] as? Int
            self.customerId = dict["customer_id"]
            self.entityPkValue = dict["entity_pk_value"]
            self.ratingId = dict["rating_id"] as? Int
            self.reviewId = dict["review_id"] as? Int
            self.percent = dict["percent"] as? Int
            self.value = dict["value"] as? Int
            self.ratingCode = dict["rating_code"] as? String
            self.storeId = dict["store_id"] as? Int
            self.code = dict["code"] as? Int
            self.postion = dict["position"] as? Int

        }
}
```

Comment: Everything works fine except `ratingVotes`. Right?

Comment: yes remaining data I got  @trungduc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just Typo mistake you might copy paste your code. You can easily find it by debug here is a  small mistake you made

Observe here in `struct Reviews`

```
   if let customAttribute = dict["reviews"] as? [[String: Any]] {
        var result = [RatingVotes]()
        for obj in customAttribute {
            result.append(RatingVotes(dict: (obj as? [String : Any])!))
        }
        self.ratingVotes = result
    } else {
        self.ratingVotes = [RatingVotes]()
    }
```

You are using key  `reviews` here  `dict["reviews"]`

it should be  `rating_votes` like  `dict["rating_votes"]`

Hope it is helpful to you

Comment: @user0246 Your Response  You have String  in value in `ratting_votes` dictionary while you are using  `self.value = dict["value"] as? Int` will always fail. Please observe response correctly before start actual implementation

Comment: ya problem with this only I replaced it with string then working fine

Answer (score 0):

You have getting both time review dictionary same value.
**if let customAttribute = dict["reviews"] as? [[String: Any] So change here 'review' to 'rating_votes'**

Or follow below code may it help you!!

```
init(dict : [String:Any]) {
    if let customAttribute = dict["rating_votes"] as? [[String: Any]] {
        var result = [RatingVotes]()
        for obj in customAttribute {
            result.append(RatingVotes(dict: (obj as? [String : Any])!))
        }
        self.ratingVotes = result
    } else {
        self.ratingVotes = [RatingVotes]()
    }
    self.reviewId = dict["review_id"]
    self.createdAt = dict["created_at"]
    self.entityId = dict["entity_id"]
    self.entityValue = dict["entity_pk_value"]
    self.statusId = dict["status_id"]
    self.detailId = dict["detail_id"]
    self.title = dict["title"] as? String
    self.detail = dict["detail"] as? String
    self.nickName = dict["nickname"] as? String
    self.customerId = dict["customer_id"]
    self.entityCode = dict["entity_code"]
 }
}
```